# Why does pagination go to a blank page when navigating through home.php?

Tags: pagination, blog

Learning how to build WordPress themes from scratch I have run into an issue when I try to code my `home.php`.  The issue I run into is with the pagination.  After the last page of posts instead of stopping/disabling the button it still enables the button and once clicked it loaded `/page/#` using the `index.php` file which at this time is just the `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>`.  The functions I have tested are with `<?php next_posts_link(); ?>` and `<?php echo get_next_posts_link(); ?>`.  I have researched awhile on this and ran across it may have something to do with the permalinks and they are set to `post name`.

Code in `home.php`:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
    <div class="thepost">
      <div class="primecircle">
        <div class="circledate">
          <div class="blogmonth"><?php the_time('M'); ?></div>
          <div class="blogdate"><?php the_time('j'); ?></div>
          <div class="blogyear"><?php the_time('Y'); ?></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="blogcontent">
      <h1 class="blogtitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
      <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
      <div class="learnmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">learn more</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>      
<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="pagelinks">
  <ul class="tags" class="list-inline">
    <li><?php echo previous_posts_link('Back'); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo next_posts_link('Next', 5); ?></li>
  </ul>
</div>  

<?php else: ?>
    <h1 class="blogtitle">No Current blog posts at this time.</h1>      
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any suggestions or pointers on how I can properly disable `next_posts_link()` function when it reaches the last page of posts?

Edited:
Adjusted error on the function `previous_posts_link();` when I was passing it an `label` and `max_page` when it only takes a `label`.  After removing `max_page` from both functions it stopped cycling to `index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be related to `5`. The [`previous_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link) only accepts one valid parameter, and that is `$label`, you are passing two.

Secondly, the [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) does accept the second parameter `$max_pages`. Here you ara passing a value of 5, which overrides `$wp_query->max_num_pages`. So you are telling Wordpress there **are** 5 pages, regardless of the real amount of pages.

**SOLUTION:**

Simply remove `5` from your links, that should solve your problem

Comment: Is this the only code that you have on your page. Are you running any custom query on it for a slider or featured post. Why do you have index.php and home.php

Comment: Ah that worked.  I was building the `archive.php` and realized I still needed to modify `home.php`. +1 for that.

Comment: Great, glad you solved your problem. Enjoy :-)